# Intersection between pandas Series elements

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following `Series`;

```
>>> x

1    Fine A
3    Fine A Sales
4    H Fine A
5    Fine A 232
7    Fine A 321
Name: Fine List, dtype: object
```

I want to calculate the intersection between the elements which in this case `Fine A` (The desired output is just a string `Fine A`)

I found many solutions to intersection between two series but not cross the series it self.

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: The desired outcome is just a string of the intersection "Fine A"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with intersection of `set`s of column [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)ed to lists:

```
print (df['Fine List'].str.split())
1           [Fine, A]
3    [Fine, A, Sales]
4        [H, Fine, A]
5      [Fine, A, 232]
7      [Fine, A, 321]
Name: Fine List, dtype: object

from functools import reduce
a = reduce(lambda x, y: set(x) & set(y), df['Fine List'].str.split())
print (list(a))
['A', 'Fine']
```